# Perl '-s' file test operator problem

Tags: perl, file

I'm debugging a piece of code which uses the [Perl '-s'](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) function to get the size of some files.

`my $File1 = /myfolder/.../mysubfolder1/document.pdf`
`my $File2 = /myfolder/.../mysubfolder2/document.pdf`
`my $File3 = /myfolder/.../mysubfolder1/document2.pdf` (`$File3` is actually a link to `/myfolder/.../mysubfolder2/document.pdf` aka `$File2`)

The code which is buggy is:

`my $size = int((-s $File)/1024);`

Where `$File` is replaced with `$File1` - `$File3`.

For some reasons I can't explain this does not work on every file.

For `$File1` and `$File3` it works but not for `$File2`. I could understand if both `$File2` and `$File3` would not work, it would mean that the file `/myfolder/.../mysubfolder2/document.pdf` is somehow corrupt.
I even added a test `if (-e $File)|{` before the `-s` to be sure the file exists, but the three files do exist.

There is an even more strange thing: there is an `.htaccess` in `/myfolder/.../mysubfolder1/` but no `.htaccess` in `/myfolder/.../mysubfolder2/`. If it was inverse I would think the `.htaccess` would block the `-s` call somehow.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly constitutes "does not work" for $file2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If -s fails, it returns undef and sets the error in $!.  What is $!?

Comment: $! returned 'Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline'. With this I could fix the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that if you check the size of that file with "stat" you will get something less than 1024 bytes :)
your int((-s $fn)/1024) will return 0 if size is less than 1024

Comment: If you are measuring the block size of the file, you can use an idiom like `int((1023 + -s $file)/1024)`

Comment: Stat returns 1936 for filesize.

Answer (score 5):

To address the end of your comment, `.htaccess` file controls access to files **by a web server's request**. Once the user requests a URL which executes a valid permissible CGI/whatever script (I'm assuming yoour Perl code is in web context), THAT script has absolutely no permissioning issues regarding .htaccess (unless you actually code your Perl to read its contents and respect them explicitly by hand).

The only permissioning that can screw up your Perl file is the file system permissions in your OS.

To get the file size, your web user needs:

- Execute permission on the directory containing the file
- Possibly, read permission on the directory containing the file (not sure if the file size is stored in the inode?)
- Possibly, read permission on the file iteself.

If all your 3 files (2 good and 1 bad) are in the same directory, check the file's read permissions.

If they are in different directories, check the file's read perms AND directory perms.

Comment: Both directories and all 3 files have the same permissions. Directories: rwx. Files: rw.

Answer (score 4):

Change `int((-s $file)/1024)` to `sprintf('%.0f', (-s $file)/1024)` - you'll see something then, the file is probably under 1024 bytes, so the `int()` will happily return 0.